We [have] sent four backup units
Suppose a couple of police officers find a group of people wanted by the police. When they try to apprehend them, the group opens fire. The officers request help on the radio. The operator tells them that assistance is on the way. At the station, the operator informs the person in charge about the situation, and that person orders four units to be sent to the location. After arriving at the site, each unit contacts the operator to report their current status. Once all units are there, the operator reports to his superior: "Sir, all of the cars we dispatched have reached the destination." Then the officer in charge receives a call from someone of a higher rank. The higher-ranking officer asks about what's going on at the station, and the officer in charge reports:
Our unit was on patrol and located a group of suspects who opened fire when our team tried to apprehend them. [We]/[We've] sent four backup units. All of them have arrived at the site. They're trying to get the situation under control. No casualties have been reported.
Are both options acceptable in this case? If so, does using "We sent" imply a closer connection in time to the moment the patrol located the group of suspects (i.e., 'right after the incident we sent for units...'), whereas using "We've sent" would present the sending as part of the ongoing actions resulting from locating the suspects and their opening fire? Thanks.

Are you asking about American or British English? In British English, people use the present perfect to speak about a past action that they consider relevant to the present. The present perfect can be used in the same way in American English, but people often use the past simple when they consider the action finished. This is especially common with the adverbs already, just and yet.

@MichaelHarvey I'm asking about both.

Both are acceptable in either type of English, as my comment indicates.

I'd say it's valid, but stylistically "inelegant" to use Present Perfect in the sentence being queried. And it's also "valid but inelegant" not to use Present Perfect for the immediately following sentence All of them [have] arrived at the site, where the perfect form emphasizes "relevance to current context" - which itself is followed by Present Continuous They're trying to... directly referencing the current context. These sentences refer to three specific different points in time, so it's quite natural to use different verb forms for each.

And I believe when @MichaelHarvey says "finished" he doesn't mean "to have been effected" but "over and done with", old news.

We dispatched backup units and all have arrived on site is how I'd state it, but as we say in AmE, there's damn little difference.

Just to clarify, can anyone expect textbook language in a dangerous emergency?

Both are valid. In British English, people use the present perfect to speak about a past action that they consider relevant to the present.
The present perfect can be used in the same way in American English, but people often use the past simple when they consider the action finished and definitely in the past. This is especially common with the adverbs already, just, and yet.
